# Clutch problem in I20 Magna Opt Diesel

Tags: clutch-cylinder

I now replaced my clutch master cylinder and slave cylinder but still I am facing issues in gear shifting i.e when the clutch is fully floored only,I am able to shift gears.I am unable to shift gears when the clutch is half pressed or not fully pressed.Do I need to replace the clutch plate in this case??
Also,I would like to know if the brake and clutch both use the fluid from same reservoir or from respective master cylinders??

Please advise...

Thanks in advance,
Debasish

Comment: Why were the cylinders replaced in the first place?

Comment: Because my clutch got floored in completely and did not come up while I was drving.....after 10 mins,it was working fine.Then again after driving 1 km,the clutch was too hard to press but after 45 mins,it again was normal.

Answer (score 1):

- Press the clutch all the way in when you shift, you're harming
  your transmission. Why have a clutch if you're not going to
  use it when shifting? Push it in all the way.
- Don't replace the clutch plate, you almost certainly just have air in
  your clutch line. Rebleed carefully.
- They do not share the same reservoir.